# Are there any nonzero continuous multilinear functions $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, multilinear-algebra

By multilinearity of $f:\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ here I mean that, for every $(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots)\in\ell^\infty$ and $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_i+x,x_{i+1},\cdots)=f(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},\cdots)+f(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x,x_{i+1},\cdots),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R};\\
f(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},\lambda x_i,x_{i+1},\cdots)=\lambda f(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},\cdots),\quad\forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}
If we suppose that $f$ is multilinear and (pointwise) continuous, must we have $f\equiv 0$?

Of course, if $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n,\cdots)\in\ell^\infty$ has $x_i=0$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}^*$, then $f(x)=0$. By continuity we obtain that $f(x)=0$ if $\displaystyle\inf_{i\in\mathbb{N}^*}|x_i|=0$. What else can be said about $f$? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, even with just the second requirement. Assume $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x$.

Let $y^n = \left((1 + \frac 11)\cdot x_1, (1 + \frac 12)\cdot x_2, (1 + \frac 13)\cdot x_3, \ldots, (1 + \frac 1n)\cdot x_n, x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \ldots\right)$. Then $y^n$ converges in $l^\infty$, but $f(y^n) = f(x) \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)$ diverges.

Comment: That's very genius. Thank you!

Comment: Also the additivity itself leads to  $f=0.$  Indeed the additivity implies  the second condition for $\lambda\in \mathbb{Q}.$